# Skip the filenames whch do not have contents while doing a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm grepping a string in files under a directory as i don't know in which file the `string_something` exits thus I'm listing all the files and doing grep on then to identify, this works however in the echo statement i only want the the Files which have the string value found rest skip the filename in the output.

```
for i in `ls -Xl| awk '{print $NF}'`;do echo "-- $i --"; grep string "$i";done
```

Output

```
-- file1 --
-- file2 --
-- file3 --
-- file4 --
-- file5 --
-- file6 --
some output   ( all the output matching to the `string` matched)
-- file7 --
-- file8 --
-- file9 --
some output   ( all the output matching to the `string` matched)
```

Desired output..

```
-- file6 --
some output
-- file9 --
some output
```

Comment: You could just use `grep -l` ? If you need to do it this way then you probably want to capture the output of grep and then print the filename and output if it's not empty / if grep returned true.

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason it's `No. 1`)

Comment: soory guys.. i need the whole output listed where it found the `string`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,  thanks for the Bash indication ... but i am using absolute path rather wildcard `*`   such as `for files in $(ls -Xl| awk '{print $NF}); do`.

Comment: @kulfi : Not exactly the format you are looking for, but wouldn't a `grep string * /dev/null` do what you are looking for? (The /dev/null just ensures that the filename is printed even if you have only a single file in the directory).

Comment: @kulfi - it doesn't matter whether you use the absolute path or wildcards (globs) the risk of included *whitespace* or other control characters or hyphens in the path or filename are what causes problems delineated in the list of `1-6` at the link I provide. The entire [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) page is worth reading and bookmarking for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the -q option if you're just interested in the files which has the word `string` in it.

```
for files in *; do
  [[ -f $files ]] || continue          ##: Don't grep directories.
  if grep -q string -- "$files"; then  ##: Don't output anything if string is found.
    echo "$files"                      ##: Print the files which has string in it.
  fi 
done
```

This might do what you want though.

```
for files in *; do
  [[ -f $files ]] || continue                ##: Don't grep directories.
  if found=$(grep string -- "$files"); then  ##: Save successful match in the variable found 
    printf '%s\n %s\n' --"$files"-- "$found"   ##: Print the desired output.
  fi 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Grep can do it alone

```
grep -ril 'string' /path/to/search
```

From grep's help

```
$ grep --help
...
-r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse
-i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions
-l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs with selected lines
...
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
grep -rin path/to/dir -e string_to_search
```

Comment: I'd add an explanation of the grep options you're using ...?

Comment: recursive ignore-case line-number and more `grep --help`

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to simply get the names of the files containing `"string_something"` is:

```
grep -l -d skip -F 'string_something' *
```

If you insist on wrapping the filename in `"-- name --"`, then you can loop over the results of `grep` and format the output as desired, e.g.

```
for i in $(grep -l -d skip -F 'string_something' *); do
    printf -- "-- %s --\n%s\n" "$i" 'string_something'
done
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i need the output result for the matched string, it just gives the string name if matched